# Ionic 5 iOS - app runs fine on emulator but it's bugged on real device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm working on an Ionic 5 app that is working fine on Android and on the Xcode emulator, but on a real iPhone the interface gets really weird, inputs not showing what you wrote on them, labels not showing and some places with a black background colour.

Here's what I mean.

[image: wrong input]
[image: label not showing]
[image: black background]

I thought that this could be a CSS problem, turning some labels white and backgrounds black, but shouldn't it be like this on the emulator too?

As it is working on the emulator, could it be something I'm doing wrong when I'm generating the .ipa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't really a problem.

Ionic projects come with a default dark theme on the `variables.scss` file, under `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`. So, when a device is using a dark theme, Ionic applies its dark theme to the app as well.

That's why our app was looking weird, it was using Ionic's dark theme.